# PrevState with [name] in event handler

Tags: reactjs

I have two checkboxes which I want to use with just one event handler. How can I make this work?

```
 handleChange = e => {
    if (e.target.type === "checkbox") {
      return this.setState(prevState => ({
        [e.target.name]: ![prevState.e.target.name]
      }));
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I´m trying this, but it won´t revert the checkbox once it´s checked:

```
if (e.target.type === "checkbox") { this.setState(prevState => ({ [name]: !prevState[name] })); }
```

Comment: How is your state structured...?  Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Let's say `e.target.name` resolves to `foo`. State in `prevState` would be `{ foo: false }`. `[prevState.e.target.name]` will not resolve correctly because you do not have `{ e: { target: { name: 'foo' } } }` as `prevState`. I think you mean something like `!prevState[e.target.name]` if you are trying to invert the previous value of the respective input value in state.

Comment: I´m trying this, but it´s not unchecking it once it´s checked:     if (e.target.type === "checkbox") {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        [name]: !prevState[name]
      }));
    }

Answer (score 2):

Now it isn't quite clear what you are trying to accomplish. Since you are working with checkboxes I will simply guess you are trying to save whether a  checkbox is checked or not.

In this case we can use setState's merge syntax and assign target's `checked` value to it's `name`:

```
   handleChange = e => {
        if (e.target.type === "checkbox") {
          this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.checked });
        }
    }
```

---

While this isn't your question I still want to note two things about your way of using setState:

1. setState does not have a return value
2. When using the function version of setState, you wont receive the `previousState` but the `currentState`.

Comment: This does work, checkout this small example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-yalow-myqvm?fontsize=14 . If this doesn't work for you, your problem might be somewhere else. In this case please provide additional code.